# What is the best way to use a variable from one function in another function (Python)?

Tags: python, var

I am trying to code something really simple but can't figure out how to use the variable I declared in the first function, in the second function.
Any ideas you might have?

```
import random 

def request_info():
    name = input("What is your name?: ")
    email = input("What is your email?: ")

def print_user_info():
    print("Your name " + name)
    print("Your email " + email)
    num = random.randrange(100_000, 10**8)
```

Comment: You can invoke the second function from the first one, passing the variables as parameters to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a class:

```
import random 

class request_info(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = input("What is your name?: ")
        self.email = input("What is your email?: ")

    def print_user_info(self):
        print("Your name " + self.name)
        print("Your email " + self.email)
        num = random.randrange(100_000, 10**8)
        return num
    
r = request_info()
r.print_user_info()

# What is your name?:  Test
# What is your email?:  Test@gmail.com
# Your name Test
# Your email Test@gmail.com
# 90584743
```

Comment: Hey, thank you!
Can you possibly explain what the two last lines do?

Comment: @Adrian Sure, `r = request_info()` initializes the class object and assigns it to the variable `r` then you call your function, which prints out the name and email: `r.print_user_info()` However, you can also get the name and email by calling the class attributes in __init__. For example, you can do  `r = request_info()` then `print(r.name)` and `print(r.email)`

Answer (score 2):

I would just pass the variables into the other function like the following code shows:

```py
import random 

def print_user_info(name,email):
    print("Your name " + name)
    print("Your email " + email)
    num = random.randrange(100_000, 10**8)

def request_info():
    name = input("What is your name?: ")
    email = input("What is your email?: ")
    print_user_info(name,email)
```

You will of course also have to invoke the `request_info` function once so that the other function gets called.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this, but you should think of scope before anything else.

The dirtiest way is to declare a global variable that will be set outside of the function, then assigned within the function.

```
global someVariable
someVariable = None
someVariable2
someVariable2 = None

def someFunction():
    global someVariable
    someVariable = 12

    global someVariable2
    someVariable2 = 24    

someFunction()

print(someVariable)
```

This will get you by, but it's not the best way to work with variables. If all you're writing is 11 or so lines of code, it'll do the trick.

Returns is another way to handle this.

```
def someFunction():
    someVariable = 4
    someVariable2 = 13
    return (someVariable,someVariable2)

print(someFunction())
```

By having the function return a tuple will allow you to get both variables accessible to the next function.

Finally, there's classes. I would recommend Classes for more complex code as it keeps things in a nice and neat little container.

```
class myClass:
    someVariable = None
    someVariable2 = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.someVariable = 50
        self.someVariable2 = -12
        
    def retValues(self):
        someVariable = self.someVariable
        someVariable2 = self.someVariable2
        
        return (someVariable,someVariable2)

print(myClass().retValues())
```

More on Classes here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for are `return` statements, which you can use to assign the output of a function to a variable.

Here, we'll return a tuple and use multiple assignment to call the values in the tuple `name` and `email`:

```
import random 

def request_info():
    name = input("What is your name?: ")
    email = input("What is your email?: ")
    return (name, email) # this function now 'returns' this tuple

def print_user_info(name, email):
    print("Your name " + name)
    print("Your email " + email)
    num = random.randrange(100_000, 10**8)
```

So if you ran the following:

```
name, email = request_info()
print_user_info(name, email)
```

(For clarity, this is what's happening in the first line above, but you can combine it into 1 line instead of 3)

```
user_info = request.info()
name = user_info[0]
email = user_info[1]
```

Your program would run like so:

```
What is your name?: Joe Smith
What is your email?: jsmith@gmail.com
Your name Joe Smith
Your email jsmith@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it. Using a class can help share variables and functions.

```
import random 

class User:

def __init__(self, name, email):
    self.name = name
    self.email = email
    self.num = random.randrange(100_000, 10**8)

def print_info(self):
    print(f"Your name is: {self.name} \nYour email is: {self.email}")

new_user = User(input("What is your name?"), input("What is your email?"))
new_user.print_info()
```